# Upgrading from Inkscape 0.91 to 0.92 or higher breaks object dpi scaling

Tags: dpi, inkscape

Following an upgrade from Inkscape 0.91 to any newer version I found that it broke the scaling on a number of my objects which are used for interactive display.

It appears a change in the DPI setting from 90 to 69 is the issue.

When opening some of my old drawings I get a dialogue box prompt asking which action I should take; Having tried all of those with none giving me the expected (working) output.

[image: Convert old file type box]

But not all of my drawing files would trigger this dialogue but they would still have there objects rescaled on load/save.

I also tried updating the version number in the `.svg` file manually but this didn't work either.

How can I work with my original files but gain the rewards of the newer(est) version(s) of Inkscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was not alone in this problem. After much searching I found [this](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/resolution-change/) thread over on the Inkscape forum.

To summarise and make it easy for people to find without wading though all the posts there are two things you need to do/check in order to upgrade without issue.

- Install the new version to a different path if you are able.
- Backup your original files.
- With your favourite sane editor open the original `.svg` file directly and observe the header section;

`inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"`

That should be replaced with the version of Inkscape you are upgrading too. In my case it is;
`inkscape:version="1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)"`

- Next look for the height and width settings and note they may not have a unit defined as in my case;
  `width="10000"
  height="800"`

Check in your original drawing what scale you had been using for your page size. It could be `px`, `mm` etc. The update the height/width section to include those units as shows below;

`width="10000px"
 height="800px"`

- Save the edited `.svg` file.

You should then be able to open/work on your old drawings in the current version of Inkscape without breaking scaling and display compatibility.